# How Can I Use Shadowbox to Extract Text Only from Webpage?

Tags: text, joomla, shadowbox

I have an article set up in Joomla that displays Terms and Conditions for the site users.  I would like this to show up in a shadowbox when a user clicks a link.  Here is the current anchor text example:

```
<a href="pathtoarticle.php" rel="shadowbox;height=572;width=975">Terms and Conditions</a>
```

This works out great for displaying the entire web page, but what I would like to do is just display the article text on the page (plain with a white background).  Is this in someway possible with shadowbox?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly - you want to suppress the modules and other periphery from your 'page' when it is loaded in the shadowbox.

Add ?tmpl=component to the url of your link.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are some components to do this - but you may have to get creative to do it without pulling the whole page with an a href tag.

In the database there's a particular area that holds that specifically and you could write a little query to just pull that information specifically and put it in the shadowbox, but what that query would look like I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `div` element and css shadow effect.

How to show/hide div is explained here:
http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/

How you can add shadow is explained here:
http://placenamehere.com/article/384/css3boxshadowininternetexplorerblurshadow/